# MySQL multiple instances: can you specify a separate general_log/general_log_file option?

Tags: mysql

Have two working MySQL instances as well as the default instance.

I have general logging enabled on the default; this is working fine.

On the second instance, I've added:

`general_log = 1`

`general_log_file = /path/to/log/file`

under `[mysqld1]`.

Restarted the instance (using `mysqladmin` and confirmed it was not running with `mysqld_multi report 1`), started it back up again, and the only data in the log file are the connect statements from when `mysqld_multi report 1` was executed.

Are all the instance #1 queries just being logged to the default instance general log file?  The default instance is quite busy and has identical database names, tables, etc. so it's difficult to figure out right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, wrong instance, and yes you can define your own log.